# Second loop is not working

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I´m running this test with nightwatch and I have a loop inside a loop, first one runs ok but it fails going inside 2nd loop.
I wrote a console.log and returns:

```
Number of links:[object Object]
```

This is my code:
What´s the reason for not entering in loop 2?
Thanks in advance.

```
 .execute(
            function() {
                return document.querySelectorAll('.menuElementsAgregator>li').length
            },
            function(result) {
                total_links = result.value;
                console.log("Number of main links:" + total_links);
                for (var i = 2; i <= total_links; i++) {
                  (function (i) {
                      browser.waitForElementPresent('.menuElementsAgregator', 3000)
                             .click('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')>a')
                             .waitForElementVisible('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')', 2000)
                        .execute(
                                function () {
                                    return document.querySelectorAll('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-of-type(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level .has-sub .clickableTabWithLink').length
                                },
                                    function(result) {
                                    total_links2 = result.value;
                                    console.log("Number of links:" + total_links2);
                                for (var j = 2; j <= total_links2 + 1; j++) {
                                    browser.waitUntilElementIsClickable('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')')
                                           .click('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')')
                                           .waitForElementPresent('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-of-type(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level>li:nth-of-type(' + j + ').has-sub', 5000)
                                           .click(' .menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-of-type(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level>li:nth-of-type(' + j + ').has-sub  .clickableTabWithLink:first-child')
                                           .pause(1000)
                                           .waitForElementVisible('.games-list', 5000);
                                                                                                         }
                                }
                            )
                  })(i);
              }
          })
```

Comment: what are you calling this function with? It's important to know what you're using in the argument `result2`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `total_links` is not an integer but an object.

Try to replace

```
console.log("Number of main links:"+ total_links);
```

with

```
console.log("Number of main links:", total_links);
```

That will show you what's inside total_links. If you can't fix it add a comment with the content of `total_links`

Comment: console.log("Number of main links:", total_links); It didn´t work

Comment: try `console.log(total_links)`

Comment: Well, you'll need to figure out what is in the total_links2 and get a integer out of it and use it in the for cycle. Maybe total_links2 is an array of links, thank you could do `for (var j = 0; j <= total_links2.length; j++) {`

Comment: `return document.querySelectorAll('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level>.has-sub').length`  is not accepting de 'i'

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely this code would not work, because you cant use a callback in a loop like that,your index 'i' in second loop would be equal  'total_links.length' all the time. You can try this:

```
        .execute(
      function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('.menuElementsAgregator>li').length
      },
      function(result) {
        total_links = result.value;
        console.log("Number of main links:" + total_links);
        for (var i = 2; i <= total_links; i++) {
         (function(i){ // this is a closure
          browser.waitForElementPresent('.menuElementsAgregator', 3000)
            .click('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')>a')
            .waitForElementVisible('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')', 2000)
            .execute(
              function() {
                return document.querySelectorAll('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level>.has-sub').length
              },
              function(result2) {
                total_links2 = result2.value;
                console.log("Number of links:" + total_links2);
                for (var j = 0; j <= total_links2; j++) {// i = total_link.length already, before get in to this loop.
                  browser.waitForElementPresent('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level>.has-sub:nth(' + j + ')', 3000) 
                    .click('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level>.has-sub:nth(' + j + ')>a')
                    .pause(3000)
                    .waitForElementVisible('.games-list', 5000);
                }
              }
            )
            })(i) // close
        }
      }
    )
```

You should take a look at api .perform() , this will be help a a lot for this kind of work. It made my code cleaner and readable.
Ps: Spend some time to research closure.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but only today i was back to this issue. Tried your suggestion but still getting `Number of links:[object Object]`

Comment: for what i can understand `.waitForElementVisible('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-child(' + i + ')', 2000)` doesnt accept the argument `i`. I had a look at the api.perform() but was not very clear to me

Comment: Can you please give me a hand on this, still stucked with this code. Everything is working except the main part, passing the value of  `i` to this part of the code: `.execute( function () {
           return document.querySelectorAll('.menuElementsAgregator>li:nth-of-type(' + i + ')>.tsr-nav-second-level .has-sub .clickableTabWithLink').length
                                },` because if i manually put a number the rest of the code runs

Comment: give me the url and the part you want to test.

Comment: Man, it is ridiculous that you sent someone a local url (192.168).